# c++ 2d plotting tool for linux

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, plot, qpainter

I am looking for a simple c++ 2d plotting tool for Linux (to be more honest "Cross-platform").

"koolplot" is nice but I think it's for windows only since its code includes graphics.h and windows.h.

Someone suggested Qt's QPainter, but I cannot even use it to draw a single point. :'(

So, is there any help on other plotting tool or a decent tutorial on Qt's QPainter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/). It's worked well for all of my 2D applications, plus it's cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) is cross-platform GPL plotting library, and it have QMathGL widget for Qt.